# Unable to delete file on sdcard

Tags: delete, file-permissions

Can anyone tell me what the file and folders are in the picture below? I can't do anything or delete these files and folders. They are coming into my external sd-card. If I format the sdcard they are removed. If I take this sdcard out of my phone and put it into my PC I'm still unable to do anything with the files and folder.

[image: File listing on phone]

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after posting the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

These are corrupted directory entries, stored in the File Allocation Table if the card was formatted for an FAT family filesystem.  Reformatting gives you a new clean File Allocation Table, and therefore the spurious entries disappear.

Thanks to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) for providing this background:

> The name of the file system originates from the file system's prominent usage of an index table, the File Allocation Table (FAT), statically allocated at the time of formatting. The table contains entries for each cluster, a contiguous area of disk storage. Each entry contains either the number of the next cluster in the file, or else a marker indicating end of file, unused disk space, or special reserved areas of the disk. The root directory of the disk contains the number of the first cluster of each file in that directory; the operating system can then traverse the FAT table, looking up the cluster number of each successive part of the disk file as a cluster chain until the end of the file is reached. In much the same way, sub-directories are implemented as special files containing the directory entries of their respective files.